# Why is my mailfilter receiving emails for some users, but not for others, when all are included as recipients to the same message?

Tags: email, microsoft-outlook, email-filter, webmin, exchange-2013

Forgive me for being light on details, I just want to see if anyone recognises this kind of issue and can provide a likely cause.

An outlook user of my exchange server has stated that a subscription email from a company has not been received by several members of their team, despite the sending contact at that company stating they intended to send it to 2 more. They claimed that our firewall may be blocking it. Highly doubtful since we're receiving emails, unless they mean their address is grey/blacklisted, but the server already received emails from this address.

It's possible, that the sender did not actually include the correct addressed, but my users are adamant that the other company is sending them correctly.

Additionally; some users who received the email; did not receive the attachments, despite the email the exact same.

Any advice?

Comment: Any updates on your issue?

Answer (score 0):

Does this issue only occur to external users? I want to confirm if these problematic recipients receive mails successfully when you directly send mails with attachment to these problematic recipients?

What can you see in [message tracking logs](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/exchange/get-messagetrackinglog?view=exchange-ps)?

```
Get-MessageTrackingLog -recipient "user01@domian.com" -Sender "user02@domian.com"
```

- If there is no error in message tracking logs, it indicates that the
  issue is related with recipients's side.
- If there is an error in message tracking log, you could post the
  error messages for further troubleshooting.

> Additionally; some users who received the email; did not receive the attachments, despite the email the exact same.

Do these recipients have something in common? Do they in the same organization? Could you ask one of these recipients for adding your email address in safe sender list and check if the issue continues?

In addition, you could check if there are some mail flow rules or inbox rules affect the issue.